Tangent ellipses property
While tinkering with an assignment about orbital transfers I stumbled across a "property" of ellipses in 2D.
I would state the property as: If two ellipses are tangent and share a focus, then the tangent point will lie on the joining line of the two uncommon foci. A graphical representation of the property.
No matter how hard I looked, I could not find anything explaining it. I am trying to understand if this is true in the first place, and if this property has a name (or how it could be demonstrated).

Yes, it is true.  One of the properties of an ellipse is that light rays from one focus reflect off the ellipse to the other focus.  If you take the ray from the common focus and reflect it off the ellipses at the common tangent point, then since the ellipses are tangent there the reflected ray is the same for both ellipses and goes through the non-common foci.

This was a plot point in S6E8 of "How I Met Your Mother" and "Monk" S5E2.

I doubt anything can beat the answer already given, but for variety:
Another property of ellipses is that the sum of the distances of a point $X$ on the ellipse, to the two foci $A,B$ is constant:$$ |\vec{AX}|+|\vec{BX}|=c$$
This means that if $v\neq 0$ is tangent to the ellipse at $X$, then $$v\cdot\left(\frac{\vec{AX}}{|\vec{AX}|}+\frac{\vec{BX}}{|\vec{BX}|}\right)=0.$$
Intuitively this is just saying that if we move a small distance in the direction $v$, starting from $X$, then the amount we increase the distance to one of the foci, cancels the amount we decrease the distance to the other foci.
Now if we also have an ellipse with foci $A,C$ which passes through $X$, with $v$ tangent to it at $X$, then:
$$v\cdot\left(\frac{\vec{AX}}{|\vec{AX}|}+\frac{\vec{CX}}{|\vec{CX}|}\right)=0.$$
Letting $u_0, u_1,u_2$ be the unit vectors:
$$u_0=\frac{\vec{AX}}{|\vec{AX}|},\qquad u_1=\frac{\vec{BX}}{|\vec{BX}|},\qquad u_2=\frac{\vec{CX}}{|\vec{CX}|},$$
we have $(u_0+u_1)$ parallel to $(u_0+u_2)$.
However the unit disk centered at $u_0$ is convex, so the three points on its boundary $0, u_0+u_1, u_0+u_2$ cannot be collinear unless $u_1=u_2$ or $u_0=u_1$ or $u_0=u_2$.
Note $u_1=u_2$ is exactly what we are trying to prove.  Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality that $u_0=u_1$.  This means that $A,B,X$ lie in a line $L$, with $v$ orthogonal to $L$, so to first order moving a small distance along $v$ from $X$ does not change the distance to $A$, which means that $C$ must lie in $L$ too.
